# JQuery makes excessive animation queues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So today I wanted to make a simple animation that would make the button grow when I hover over the button, and shrink when I take the mouse off the button. I tried using this simple JQuery code, but the problem is that if I put the animation speed on slow, running on and off the button multiple times would create multiple queues of the animations, which will run long after my mouse has already left the button.

Is there a way to kill the queue after shrinking it if the mouse leaves the button? Obviously I would like to kill the queue after the button shrinks for the animation to be effective.

Related HTML:

```
<div id="global-nav">
    <ul id="top-nav">
        <li class="nav-list"><a class="nav" href="http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/33400000/Cats-cats-33441067-1280-800.jpg">Link1</a></li>
        |
        <li class="nav-list"><a class="nav" href="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/16100000/-cats-16140154-1920-1080.jpg">Link2</a></li>
        |
        <li class="nav-list"><a class="nav" href="http://learningfromdogs.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/cats-in-sink.jpg">Link3</a></li>
        |
        <li class="nav-list"><a class="nav" href="http://25.media.tumblr.com/55b8c778e82b28aef27be5d6da8eaa7e/tumblr_meysfu2tM91qzv52ko1_500.jpg">Link4</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Related JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            paddingTop:'6px',
            paddingRight:'4px',
            paddingBottom:'6px',
            paddingLeft:'4px'
        },"slow");  
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            paddingTop:'3px',
            paddingRight:'2px',
            paddingBottom:'3px',
            paddingLeft:'2px'
        },"slow");
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76tna/

Please excuse the other CSS, cat text, and HTML. I am referring to the buttons in the nav bar. (If you're curious, this is for my younger sister.)

Comment: I will be unavailable for the next 20 minutes for a shower break, sorry.

Comment: jQuery does a lot of excessive stuff XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**TRY THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/76tna/1/)

You need to use the [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function, but if you [look at the docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) you see that you have to remember to input `true` to the function to clear the queue because it defaults to false.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav").stop(true).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            paddingTop:'6px',
            paddingRight:'4px',
            paddingBottom:'6px',
            paddingLeft:'4px'
        },"slow");  
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({
            paddingTop:'3px',
            paddingRight:'2px',
            paddingBottom:'3px',
            paddingLeft:'2px'
        },"slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped solve a problem that has plagued me for days... I even tried using conditional loops; there was a perfect solution right here the whole time. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `.stop()` the current animation before starting the next one, otherwise it will queue as you currently observe.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css({
            paddingTop:'6px',
            paddingRight:'4px',
            paddingBottom:'6px',
            paddingLeft:'4px',
            transition: 'padding 0.3s ease'            
    }); 
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css({
        paddingTop:'3px',
        paddingRight:'2px',
        paddingBottom:'3px',
        paddingLeft:'2px',
        transition: 'padding 0.3s ease'
    });

});
});
```

Comment: You can use "stop()" and also as my answer.